# Капча до AJAX запроса.

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Суть в чём, нужно отправить файл на сервер с помощью AJAX и нужно сделать проверку капчёй. То есть алгоритм примерно такой:

1. Проверяем капчу, если всё хорошо переходим к шагу 2.
2. Отправляем файл и форму с капчёй из шага 1.
3. На сервере проверяем капчу, если всё хорошо работаем с файлом.

Зачем такое усложнение? Проверку капчи желательно сделать ДО начала загрузки файла на сервер, так-как не очень приятно когда грузишь большой файл на сервер а потом выскакивает окно, мол "А вы капчу не правильно ввели". Я реализовал это с помощью reCapcha. Но возникает проблема, после первой проверки без загрузки файла, вторая проверка уже с файлом ошибочная. Я примерно представляю из-за чего это происходит, но методы решения найти не могу. Так же, может я делаю что-то не так и стоит использовать другой алгоритм?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что если сделать первый AJAX запрос на проверку капчи, и в случае успеха - установка сессии на одобрение загрузки, далее посыл второго запроса AJAX на загрузку файла с проверкой сессии?

Comment: Думал об этом, пожалуй это лучший вариант :)

Comment: Только в этом случае, у формы сделайте token какой-то, чтобы не получилось так, что капчу вводит с одной страницы, а файл посылает безнаказанно с другой.

Comment: А какая разница? Пускай хоть так загружает, это не особо важно я думаю... Потому что без сессии пользователь ничего не сделает.